# Forbid word breaking (ConTeXt)

Tags: line-breaking, context, brackets

In the following example

```
\definefont[Shehkl][name:Scheherazade*arabic at 15pt] % or file:amiri-regular.ttf*... file:alq.ttf

\definestartstop[Arab][commands=\setups{Arabic}]
\def\Arab{\doArab}
\def\Arab[#1]{
\startArab 
\noindentation
            \setupalign[r2l]\Shehkl#1
\stopArab
}

\starttext

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (Fitra -\Arab[فطرة])

\stoptext
```

the last bracket in `(Fitra -\Arab[فطرة])` is set into the next line - a mistake of course. One way to avoid that (caused by not correctly handling arabic?) would be to put it all into something like `\neverbrakethis[]` - which I know from LaTeX, what is the equivalent here - or are there better solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about arabic typesetting, but your ConTeXt source does not appear to be right. Why not use the following, which is simpler and much more direct:

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]

\definesimplefont[arabicfont][Scheherazade][size=15pt, features=arabic]

\startsetups arabic
  \righttoleft
  \language[ar]
\stopsetups

\definestartstop
  [arabic]
  [commands=\setups{arabic}, style=\arabicfont]


\starttext

English text \arabic{arabic text} english text

\startarabic
  .... arabic paragraph
\stoparabic

\stoptext
```

**Notes**:

1. Ideally, in ConTeXt you want to switch to a complete typescript rather than just switch the main font. With typescripts, font variants such as bold, italic, sans bold, work correctly. I don't know if those variants make sense for Arabic.
2. I am using the simplefonts module simply because I find it more convenient compared to the low level font commands.

Comment: Your code does not work, try some arabic word (f.e. mine of the above example). But with `hbox` it now works.

Comment: Which version of context are you using (output of `context --version`)? I tested with the input in your example, and do not get any line break between the arabic text and close parenthesis. You do not need a `\hbox`.

Comment: Yes, but check the arabic output, the letters are not connected anymore, like it should be. I am using `2012.05.30 11:26`

Comment: Try with `features=arabic` in definesimplefonts (see updates answer).